# How can make a axiom in Z3Py correctly?

Tags: python, z3, z3py

I am working in this axiom ForAll X( f(x) > 0 -> b == True) .

How I could to do it in Z3Py? I try to do this:

```
from z3 import *

Z = IntSort()
f = Function('f', Z, Z)
g = Function('g', Z, Z)
a, n, x = Ints('a n x')
b = BoolSort()
solve(ForAll(x,Implies(f(x) > 0,b ==True)))
```

but Python return me `AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'ast'`

Answer (score 1):

You can declare `b` as `b = Bool('b')`. Then it works.

By the way, you can replace `b == True` by just `b` as in

`solve(ForAll(x,Implies(f(x) > 0, b )))`.

`BoolSort` etc. are meant for parameters to Z3Py functions, not for variables.

Answer (score 1):

What's your axiom trying to state? Note that in the formula `ForAll X. (f(x) > 0 -> b == True)`, `b` is a free variable. So, this doesn't really seem to correspond to anything logical. But, if that's what you really want to say, this is how you'd code it:

```py
from z3 import *

Z = IntSort()
f = Function('f', Z, Z)
g = Function('g', Z, Z)
a, n, x = Ints('a n x')
b = Bool('b')
solve(ForAll(x,Implies(f(x) > 0, b)))
```

And we get:

```
$ python a.py
[b = False, f = [else -> 0]]
```

What's z3 telling us? It says, OK, I'll pick `f` to be a function that maps everything to `0`. So, your implication will have a antecedent `0 > 0`, which is always `false`, and thus the implication is always true. (False implies anything.) The choice for `False` for `b` in the model is really irrelevant.

So, z3 did find you a model for `f` and `b` that satisfied your quantified assertion. Just like you asked. But I suspect this wasn't really the formula you were trying to assert. Axioms are typically closed: That is, they have no free variables, other than the uninterpreted functions symbols they include. Of course, this all depends on what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but if the axioms don't have free variables, how I can to do it? I want to do that ForAll X f(x) > 0 then back True, but I only write the way I came up with. Maybe I have a bad conception of axioms, but I think that when I write a axiom I have to demostrate the precondition and when te precondition is true, then I don't know if Z3 back me the postcondition or I have to write it, how is it?

Comment: @SergiSanz I think the confusion comes from trying to view Z3 as an imperative language, where you set variables, can execute loops etc.. In Z3 on the contrary, you define logical conditions between variables and Z3 does its magic to find variables that satisfy those.

Comment: @SergiSanz I suspect you might be experiencing the XY problem here. (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) Instead of asking roundabout questions regarding some encodings, please ask directly about what you are trying to model. The more concrete your question is, the better the answers will be. I've a feeling what you're after are not really quantified axioms.